# Erro: Could not find class 'com.google.android.chimera.Activity' ... did not call through to super.onResume()

Tags: android

Estou tentando integrar um scanner ao meu aplicativo e, a principio, fiz idêntico ao que está no github:

https://github.com/KingsMentor/MobileVisionBarcodeScanner

Porém, quando chamo a ActivityScanner acontece o erro:

> 02-17 20:25:31.058 26651-26735/br.codes.locadoraFilmes E/dalvikvm: Could
>   not find class 'com.google.android.chimera.Activity', referenced from
>   method mu.b 02-17 20:25:31.088 26651-26651/br.codes.locadoraFilmes
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         Process: br.codes.locadoraFilmes, PID: 26651
>                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {br.codes.locadoraFilmes/br.codes.locadoraFilmes.view.ActivityScanner}:
>   android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity
>   {br.codes.locadoraFilmes/br.codes.locadoraFilmes.view.ActivityScanner} did
>   not call through to super.onResume()
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2254)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
>                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                          Caused by: android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity
>   {br.codes.locadoraFilmes/br.codes.locadoraFilmes.view.ActivityScanner} did
>   not call through to super.onResume()
>                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5326)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819) 
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2254) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
>                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  02-17 20:25:31.158
>   2763-24817/? E/Vision: Download Failed: Status{statusCode=Download not
>   allowed: Não há espaço suficiente para fazer o download.,
>   resolution=null}

**activity_scanner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.ActivityScanner">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/actions"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/barcode"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.BarcodeCapture"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            app:gvb_auto_focus="true"
            app:gvb_code_format="all_format"
            app:gvb_flash="false"
            app:gvb_rect_colors="@array/rect_color" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/actions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/focus"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="auto focus" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/draw_rect"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="draw rect" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp">


            <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/support_multiple"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="support multiple" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/touch_callback"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="touch callback" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/draw_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="draw text" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/from_xml"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="From xml" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/refresh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Refresh" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**ActivityScanner.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.BarcodeCapture;
import com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.BarcodeGraphic;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;

import java.util.List;

import br.codes.locadoraFilmes.R;
import xyz.belvi.mobilevisionbarcodescanner.BarcodeRetriever;

public class ActivityScanner extends FragmentActivity implements BarcodeRetriever{
    SurfaceView preview = null;
    SurfaceHolder previewHolder = null;
    Camera camera;
    boolean inPreview = false;
    boolean cameraConfigured = false;
    Dialog dialog;
    Permissao p = new Permissao();
    String tipoActivity = "";
    ImageView buscaManual,buscaPorNome;

    private static final String TAG = "BarcodeMain";

    CheckBox fromXMl;
    SwitchCompat drawRect, autoFocus, supportMultiple, touchBack, drawText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);


        final BarcodeCapture barcodeCapture = (BarcodeCapture) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.barcode);
        barcodeCapture.setRetrieval(this);

        fromXMl = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.from_xml);
        drawRect = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.draw_rect);
        autoFocus = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.focus);
        supportMultiple = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.support_multiple);
        touchBack = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.touch_callback);
        drawText = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.draw_text);

        findViewById(R.id.refresh).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (fromXMl.isChecked()) {

                } else {
                    barcodeCapture.setShowDrawRect(drawRect.isChecked());
                    barcodeCapture.setSupportMultipleScan(supportMultiple.isChecked());
                    barcodeCapture.setTouchAsCallback(touchBack.isChecked());
                    barcodeCapture.shouldAutoFocus(autoFocus.isChecked());
                    barcodeCapture.setShouldShowText(drawText.isChecked());
                    barcodeCapture.refresh();
                }
            }
        });
@Override
    public void onRetrieved(final Barcode barcode) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Barcode read: " + barcode.displayValue);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityScanner.this)
                        .setTitle("code retrieved")
                        .setMessage(barcode.displayValue);
                builder.show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRetrievedMultiple(final Barcode closetToClick, final List<BarcodeGraphic> barcodeGraphics) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String message = "Code selected : " + closetToClick.displayValue + "\n\nother " +
                        "codes in frame include : \n";
                for (int index = 0; index < barcodeGraphics.size(); index++) {
                    Barcode barcode = barcodeGraphics.get(index).getBarcode();
                    message += (index + 1) + ". " + barcode.displayValue + "\n";
                }
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityScanner.this)
                        .setTitle("code retrieved")
                        .setMessage(message);
                builder.show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapScanned(SparseArray<Barcode> sparseArray) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRetrievedFailed(String s) {

    }
```

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="br.codes.locadoraFilmes"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardwar.ListaProe.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        tools:node="replace"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="SocialMarket"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="barcode"/>
...
</aplication>
</manifest>
```

Peço desculpas pelo quantidade de código. Imagino que o erro esteja em alguma dessas partes mas nao tenho ideia de qual.